# Angular configuration using the cognito Hosted UI with AWS ALB

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito, aws-application-load-balancer

Configured cognito authentication in ALB and forwarding to Angular v12.
Cookies and request headers are sent from ALB to Angular.
Request headers are not accessible to Angular as it is client side framework.
How to get the headers? Below is the reference link from AWS doc.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-authenticate-users.html

I tried with subscribe the url again. In response header, 'x-amzn-oidc-*' are not fetched.